# Understanding clients and servers

Tags: java, caching, ignite

I'm pretty much new to ignite and have a question about responsibility of client and server nodes. As far as I got from the documentation client nodes are very small machines, so it's not their purpose to perform some heavy cache operations. For instance I need to load data from some persistence store, perform some heavy cache-related computations and put resulting data into cache. It looks like this:

I.

```
//This is on a client node
public class Loader{

private DataSource dataSource;

@IgniteInstanceResource
private Ignite ignite;

    public void load(){
        String key;
        String values;
        //retreive key and value from the dataSource
        IgniteDataStreamer<String, String> streamer = ignite.dataStreamer("cache");
        String result;
        //process value
        streamer.addData(key, result); //<---------1
    }

}
```

The question is about `//1`. Is it client's node responsibility to process loaded data and put it into cache? I actually have intention to do the following: create task for each loaded `String key` and `String value` and perform all evaluation and cache related operations on a server node. Like the following:

II.

```
public class LoaderJob extends ComputeJobAdapter{
    private String key;
    private String value;

    @Override
    public Object execute(){
        //perform all computation and putting into cache here
        //and return Tuple2(key, result);
    }
}

public class LoaderTask extends extends ComputeTaskSplitAdapter<Void, Void {

   //...

    public Void reduce(List<ComputeJobResult> results) throws IgniteException {
        results.stream().forEach(result -> {
            Tuple2<String, String> jobResult = result.getData();
            ignite.dataStreamer("cache").addData(jobResult._1, jobResult._2);
        });
        return null;
    } 
}
```

In the second case what the client is doing is just to load data from the persistance store and then publishing tasks on servers.

What is the common way of doing things like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on amount of data and computational complexity. In case of big amount of data you can load data right from server, without using client.

[Here](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/CacheDataStreamerExample.java) is the simplest example for DataStreamer, you need only to add loading data from your persistent store and do calculations before using DataStreamer.

Also, it depends on other things, like a client confuguration(CPU, RAM, network) and connection between client and server nodes. If client have a good configuration, for example, as a server, and it's in the same network as a server nodes, then it's not a problem to make load and computations on client and only after it stream data to cache.

Comment: There is gonna be about 25 TB of data. So, good point... I was afraid of the cost of serialization.

Answer (score 2):

Creating dedicate job for some data by yourself, is bad idea. Something like this doing in streamer (data will be buffered and sent to specific node where are will be stored).

> client nodes are very small machines, so it's not their purpose to perform some heavy cache operations

This is not a true statement. You are able to give enough resource to client JVM, to load data.

You should create one data streamer on client side and load data from this machine. Also streamer instance is thread save, so you can load date from some threads simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

IgniteDataStreamer is the the fastest way to load data in a cache. So, the first case is valid.

I think, the second case make sense if a data will be gathered from persistence store on the server nodes and client send only parameters of the loading.